# Smooth change header's height when u click on menu item

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I want to do effect collapse or some similar

But when I click on menu item height is change so fast without animation

Whats wrong in my code?

Reference effect like here in header https://x.rarible.com/

My vue & scss code

```
<Transition name="collapse" appear>
<div class="header" @mouseleave="closeHeader">
  <div class="header__general">
    <Icon name="logo" color="white" class="header__logo" />

    <div class="header__links">
      <p
        v-for="item of MENU_ITEMS"
        :key="item"
        class="header__link"
        @click="setCurrentMenuItem(item)"
      >
        {{ item }}
      </p>
    </div>

    <SocialIcons color="white" />

    <div class="header__button">
      <Button :text="buttonText" @click="openWalletModal" />
    </div>

    <div class="header__menu" @click="openWalletModal">
      <Icon name="menu" color="white" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <TransitionGroup name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
    <Component :is="menuComponent" :key="currentMenuItem" />
  </TransitionGroup>
</div>
```

```
            .fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapse-enter-from,
.collapse-leave-to {
  background: transparent;
  max-height: 0;
}
.collapse-enter-active,
.collapse-leave-active {
  transition: max-height 4s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

- Ensure that when expanding, `max-height` has a specific value. It will work if it will have specific values.

Here related question:

[How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)